# Secure GCP servless with IaaS appliance

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to access GCP PaaS (App Engine , Cloud Function, Cloud Run) internally (throught VPC)

I see in this doc : https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access
"Serverless VPC Access only allows requests to be initiated by the serverless environment. Requests initiated by a VM must use the external address of your serverless service—see Private Google Access for more information."

But searching for something like "Serverless VPC Access allows in/out requests"

Comment: Can you provide more details about intended use? Perhaps you can use external IP to trigger internal connection?

Comment: The goal is to control in/out PaaS traffic by passing it through a Network appliance on a VPC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 ways: in and out

**Request TO serverless APP**

You can use ingress control with [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings#ingress_settings) and [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/ingress) services. You can say: I want that only connections from my VPC (or VPC SC perimeter) access to my serverless APP. With App Engine, you have firewall rules but doesn't work with private IP.

**Request FROM serverless APP**

Here you want to reach private resource exposed only on your VPC with a private IP. And with [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/connecting-vpc), [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/connecting-vpc) and [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/connecting-vpc), you can plug a [serverless VPC connector](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access) to achieve this.

---

**EDIT 1**

With your appliance firewall deployed on Google Cloud, App Engine isn't the perfect product for this. Indeed, with App Engine you can't control the ingress traffic, and you always accept the traffic from the internet, even if you have a stuff (here your appliance) already on Google Cloud Network with a private IP.

The solution here (to test, depends on the appliance capacity) is to use [Cloud NAT](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview) and to route all the traffic of the subnet on which the appliance is deployed, and to use a reserved static IP.

Then, on App Engine, you can [set a firewall rule](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/creating-firewalls) to accept only traffic from this reserved static IP.

The latency will increase with all these layers...

Comment: Hello @guillaume and thanks for detailed explanation. Lets say I want to use a firewall based on a Appliance (IaaS resource I mean), would it be possible for App Engine? Like you say, firewall rules to secure App Engine. My goal would be to publish the App Engine using a Firewall Appliance. You think this could be feasible?

Comment: It's not clear for me from where the traffic is originated? From App Engine? From outside? And where is located your firewall appliance? On Prem?

Comment: Traffic from outside and a firewall appliance on CGP (third party tool). Means outside traffic goes to a third party firewall that you manage as an appliance on GCP before entering the App Engine.

Comment: I updated my answer with a possible solution. You need to test it to be sure that works!

Comment: Thanks Guillaume, that would give. I'm pretty sure it will work but as you said bad design. I will instead review my needs..